# date comparison in EF query

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

I have a EF query in which i'm using lambda expressions, when i try to get the difference between two dates, it throws me exception

The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.

my query is

```
var unApprovedLeaves = db.Leaves.Where(l => l.Status.Id == 1 && ((System.DateTime.Now.Date - l.ToDate.Date).TotalDays)==0)
    .Include("Employee")
    .Include("Employee.Manager")
    .ToList();
```

can anyone tell me how do i get this thing right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `SqlFunctions` helper from `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`. Try this:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var unApprovedLeaves = db.Leaves.Where(l => l.Status.Id == 1 && 
                                      (SqlFunctions.DateDiff("day", today, l.ToDate))==0)
    .Include("Employee")
    .Include("Employee.Manager")
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In Entity Framework it is recomended to use `DbFunctions` helper from `System.Data.Entity`

Try this:

```
var today = DateTime.Now.Date;
var unApprovedLeaves = db.Leaves.Where(l => l.Status.Id == 1 && 
                                      (DbFUnction.DiffDays(today, l.ToDate))==0)
    .Include("Employee")
    .Include("Employee.Manager")
    .ToList();
```